# Bash shell customizations

Tags: bash, ubuntu-mate, inputrc

I understand that the bashrc and inputrc are used to configure the shell.  I'm also assuming that making changes to the versions in `/etc` apply to all users and the versions in `~./` are for the current user.

So if for example `/etc/inputrc` and `~/.inputrc` are identical have different settings, which one takes priority?

I am trying to add history search from the command prompt while typing and I don't seem to have a `~./inputrc`.  One suggestion I saw was to copy the one from `/etc/inputrc` to `~./inputrc` and then add the lines in my `~./inputrc`.  But why do that instead of just creating a new `~./inputrc` and adding the lines there, assuming they will be "merged" with what is in the `/etc/inputrc`?  What is the right/best way to handle these types of tweaks?

Comment: `inputrc` is used to configure the Readline library, which is used not just by `bash`, but by other programs as well.

Answer (score 5):

You always want to add the lines to your local `~/.inputrc`, it will be "merged" with the global one in places where you haven't made any tweaks.

I think people tend to suggest copying the global file because then you don't get any surprises if the global file is updated during an upgrade (though in practice, I find this to be incredibly rare and there's usually a good reason for the change).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I assumed, but what had me doubting is that tab completion was not working on my bash terminal until I uncommented the appropriate section in my /etc/bashrc.  However, the sections were already uncommented in my ~/.bashrc.  So does the "local" file specific to my user not take priority?  In that case I'm thinking it would be best to make the change in /etc/...

Comment: The local one definitely takes priority, I'm wondering if there's something else going on here, like something earlier in your local file over-riding the customization.

Comment: Got it.  Confirms my assumptions.  I'll just have to do a compare and figure out what is off. Thanks again.